# PayPal API Confusion - Which one to use for ExpressCheckout

Tags: c#, paypal

I'm looking at the various integrations PayPal offer and as I just want to offer PayPal as a payment options, I'm going with Express Checkout. That being said, there are numerous ways this can be integrated it seems:

1. Name Value Pairs
2. Classic API (SDKs)
3. Restful API.

The issue I have is that the .NET SDK is part of the classic API set which is apparently being deprecated (source: https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-dotnet). The RESTful API doesn't mention anything about ExpressCheckout so I am *assuming* NVP is the way to go.

Can someone clarify the best route to go down as I'd rather not have to rewrite it if things are being deprecated.

For info: I'm using ASP.NET MVC with C#.

Comment: Just for further clarification/addition to the answer below, the ".Net SDK" for REST is available on [Github](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK) and also distributed via [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPal). Hth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, there are only two APIs:

1. [Classic API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/#ec)

   - Request and response payloads are formatted as `NVP and SOAP`.
   - Official PayPal SDK support for Express Checkout available with the **PayPal Merchant SDK for .NET** ([GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-dotnet) | [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPalMerchantSDK/))
2. [REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#payments)

   - Request and response payloads are formatted as `JSON`
   - Official PayPal SDK support available with the **PayPal .NET SDK** ([GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK) | [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPal))

The [PayPal Name-Value Pair API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/NVPAPIOverview/) (NVP API) enables you to leverage the functionality of the PayPal API by simply sending an HTTP request to PayPal and specifying request parameters using name-value pairs. The NVP API is a lightweight alternative to the PayPal SOAP API and provides access to the same set of functionality as the SOAP API.

A few points to consider with respect to Classic API vs. REST API:

- Classic API is not going to be deprecated any time soon. You can use Classic API.
- Moreover REST API does not support many variables/parameters that work in Classic API.
- REST API can be used for both credit card and PayPal payments (express checkout architecture).

Since you are using .NET SDK, you can continue using it as it uses Classic API+NVP.

Comment: Right, excellent. Many thanks for your time (and for clearing up my confusion).

Comment: @Vimalnath - Does Classical API not support PayPal payments but only credit card payments? It seems from the last bullet point you posted that this may be true.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer SOAP because is a clean code, with classes.

Look adapted C# code:

```
private paypalProxy.CustomSecurityHeaderType getCredentials()
{
  paypalProxy.CustomSecurityHeaderType header = new paypalProxy.CustomSecurityHeaderType();
  header.Credentials = new paypalProxy.UserIdPasswordType();

  header.Credentials.Username = ""; 
  header.Credentials.Password = ""; 
  header.Credentials.Signature = ""; 
  header.Credentials.Subject = "";

  return header;
}

private paypalProxy.BasicAmountType getAmountValue(Decimal valor)
{
  paypalProxy.BasicAmountType amt = new paypalProxy.BasicAmountType();
  amt.currencyID = paypalProxy.CurrencyCodeType.BRL;
  amt.Value = valor.ToString("N2").Replace(",", ".");

  return amt;
}

public paypalProxy.SetExpressCheckoutResponseType ExpressCheckout(Venda venda, string emailComprador, Decimal valor, Decimal valorFrete, string shipToName, string shipToStreet, string shipToStreet2, string shipToCity, string shipToState, string shipToZip, string shipToCountryCode, string billingToName, string billingToStreet, string billingToStreet2, string billingToCity, string billingToState, string billingToZip, string billingToCountryCode)
{
  #region Header/Identification
  paypalProxy.CustomSecurityHeaderType header = getCredentials();
  #endregion

  #region Body
  paypalProxy.SetExpressCheckoutReq requisicao = new paypalProxy.SetExpressCheckoutReq();

  #region Body configuration
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest = new paypalProxy.SetExpressCheckoutRequestType();
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.Version = "109.0";            
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = new paypalProxy.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType();
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.OrderTotal = getAmountValue(valor + valorFrete - venda.valorFreteDesconto);
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.BuyerEmail = emailComprador;
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.ReturnURL = ""
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.CancelURL = ""
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.PaymentAction = paypalProxy.PaymentActionCodeType.Sale;
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.ReqConfirmShipping = "0";
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.AddressOverride = "0";
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.AllowNote = "0";
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.BrandName = "" 
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.ShippingMethod = ShippingServiceCodeType.CustomCode;
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.cppheaderimage = "http://.../logo.jpg"
  #endregion

  #region Shipping Details
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.Address = new paypalProxy.AddressType();
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.Address.Name = shipToName;
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.Address.Street1 = shipToStreet;
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.Address.Street2 = shipToStreet2;
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.Address.CityName = shipToCity;
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.Address.StateOrProvince = shipToState;
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.Address.PostalCode = shipToZip;
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.Address.Country = paypalProxy.CountryCodeType.BR;
  #endregion

  #region Billing Address
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.BillingAddress = new paypalProxy.AddressType();
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.BillingAddress.Name = billingToName;
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.BillingAddress.Street1 = billingToStreet;
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.BillingAddress.Street2 = billingToStreet2;
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.BillingAddress.CityName = billingToCity;
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.BillingAddress.StateOrProvince = billingToState;
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.BillingAddress.PostalCode = billingToZip;
  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.BillingAddress.Country = paypalProxy.CountryCodeType.BR;
  #endregion

  #region Payment detail
  PaymentDetailsType paymentDetail = new PaymentDetailsType();

  #region ITEMS
  List<PaymentDetailsItemType> paymentItems = new List<PaymentDetailsItemType>();
  foreach (var item in venda.Product)
  {
     PaymentDetailsItemType itemPaypal = new PaymentDetailsItemType();
     itemPaypal.Name = item.Produto;
     //itemPaypal.Description = item.ProductName;
     itemPaypal.Amount = getAmountValue(item.value);
     itemPaypal.Quantity = item.qtd.ToString();
     itemPaypal.ItemURL = item.UrlImage;   

     paymentItems.Add(itemPaypal);                
  }

  #region DISCOUNT
  if (venda.isDesconto)
  {
     PaymentDetailsItemType itemPaypal = new PaymentDetailsItemType();
     itemPaypal.Name = "Discount";
     itemPaypal.Description = "Discount";
     itemPaypal.Amount = getAmountValue(venda.Discount * (-1));
     itemPaypal.Quantity = "1";                

     paymentItems.Add(itemPaypal);
   }
   #endregion

  paymentDetail.ItemTotal = getAmountValue(valor);
  #endregion

  #region Shipping
  if (ShippingValue > 0)
  {
    paymentDetail.ShippingTotal = getAmountValue(ShippingValue);                
  }

  if (venda.ShippingDiscount > 0)
  {
    paymentDetail.ShippingDiscount = getAmountValue(venda.ShippingDiscount);
  }
  #endregion

  paymentDetail.OrderDescription = string.Format("SALE {0} Nº {1}", "XPTO eCommerce", "Sale ID");
  paymentDetail.PaymentDetailsItem = paymentItems.ToArray();
  paymentDetail.AllowedPaymentMethod = AllowedPaymentMethodType.AnyFundingSource;
  paymentDetail.InvoiceID = venda.IdVenda.ToString();            

  List<PaymentDetailsType> paymentDetails = new List<PaymentDetailsType>();
  paymentDetails.Add(paymentDetail);            

  requisicao.SetExpressCheckoutRequest.SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.PaymentDetails = paymentDetails.ToArray();
  #endregion
  #endregion

  #region Sending to Paypal and waiting for token in var TIPO
  paypalProxy.SetExpressCheckoutResponseType tipo = null;
  paypalProxy.PayPalAPIAAInterfaceClient cliente = new paypalProxy.PayPalAPIAAInterfaceClient();
  tipo = cliente.SetExpressCheckout(ref header, requisicao);
  #endregion

  return tipo;
}
```

Comment: Same for the [REST API](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPal). Decision (for new development) on which to implement, is based more on **feature** support (perhaps not yet supported in REST API). Hth.